# Animate UIImage in UIImageView Up & Down (Like it's hovering) Loop

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, core-animation, ios6

Hello I have an image that I'd like to move up and down (Up 10 pixels and down 10 pixels) so that my image appears to be hovering. How can I do this with simple animation thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use Core Animation to animate the position of the views layer. If you configure the animation to be `additive` you won't have to bother calculating the new absolute position, just the change (relative position).

```
CABasicAnimation *hover = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
hover.additive = YES; // fromValue and toValue will be relative instead of absolute values
hover.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointZero];
hover.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, -10.0)]; // y increases downwards on iOS
hover.autoreverses = YES; // Animate back to normal afterwards
hover.duration = 0.2; // The duration for one part of the animation (0.2 up and 0.2 down)
hover.repeatCount = INFINITY; // The number of times the animation should repeat
[myView.layer addAnimation:hover forKey:@"myHoverAnimation"];
```

Since this is using Core Animation you will need to add QuartzCore.framework and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` into your code.

Comment: Aww man this worked way better! Not only was it easier to understand but I could actually try out different values that made sense! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 9):

For Swift 3, Swift 4 and Swift 5:

```
let hover = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    
hover.isAdditive = true
hover.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.zero)
hover.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 100.0))
hover.autoreverses = true
hover.duration = 2
hover.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    
myView.layer.add(hover, forKey: "myHoverAnimation")
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
CGRect frm_up = imageView.frame;
frm_up.origin.y -= 10;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    delay:0.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeats
    animations:^{
        imageView.frame = frm_up;
    }
    completion:NULL
];
```

Comment: It works awesome! The only thing is that it moves up and to the left. Diagonal like as if it's going to the 0,0 mark.

Comment: @Year3000 how's that? 1. I'm doing absolutely nothing to the X direction of the frame. 2. The only thing I change is the y position, however that is supposed to be autoreversed (see the `options` argument of the method call). I'm sure you're missing something.

Comment: IDK It's weird. My frame is (86, 198, 132, 217) & I'm using what you recommended and it's like the center of the imageView heads to 0,0.

Comment: how to rotate image in top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

For such a task, it will be better to place an image in a sublayer of `UIView`, and then animate that sublayer frame. This tutorial could give you some idea: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/introduction-to-calayers-tutorial

Comment: The tutorial you linked to doesn't explain how to do the animation.

Comment: Operations on layers are automatically animated.

Comment: Yes, they have implicit animations if they are standalone layers but these don't animate back etc.