# Move and animate UIImageView using swift

Tags: uiimageview, swift, ios8, quartz-core

I have what should be a fairly simple question here. Basically I'm trying to move an object (a UIImageView) from a point A (where it is set in the storyboard) to a point B which I define programatically.

My first pass through this resulted in this code

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.signInButton.alpha = 1
            self.signInButton.center.y = 10
        }, completion: nil)
```

However, what this code does is to basically move the button offcenter and then back to its original location.

I then looked into QuartzCore to help me, but everything is in Objective-C. I have this method:

```
    func moveImage(view: UIImageView){
        var toPoint: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, -10.0)
        var fromPoint : CGPoint = CGPointZero

        var movement = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "movement")
        movement.additive = true
        movement.fromValue = fromPoint
        movement.toValue = toPoint
        movement.duration = 0.3

        view.layer.addAnimation(movement, forKey: "move")
    }
```

However the problem here is that `movement.fromValue` cannot accept a `CGPoint`. I know that in objective C there was a function that converted a `CGPoint` to a `NSValue`, however this function seems to be deprecated out of Swift and I can't find the other way of doing this.

**Therefore my question is either, how do I convert `CGPoint` to `NSValue` to make my `moveImage()` function work, or is there a better way to move an object from point A to point B?**

Thanks!

I'm looking at this question [Animate UIImage in UIImageView Up & Down (Like it's hovering) Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881150/animate-uiimage-in-uiimageview-up-down-like-its-hovering-loop)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `NSValue(CGPoint: cgpiont)` instead of `NSValue.valueWithCGPoint(<#point: CGPoint#>)` which is deprecated in swift. `NSValue(CGPoint: cgpiont)` is constructor given for that which can be used to convert `CGPoint` to `NSValue`
in swift.Following code will work

```
func moveImage(view: UIImageView){
    var toPoint: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, -10.0)
    var fromPoint : CGPoint = CGPointZero

    var movement = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "movement")
    movement.additive = true
    movement.fromValue =  NSValue(CGPoint: fromPoint)
    movement.toValue =  NSValue(CGPoint: toPoint)
    movement.duration = 0.3

    view.layer.addAnimation(movement, forKey: "move")
}
```

Comment: huh awesome, that was easy. Ok ya that works perfectly to convert it. You wouldn't happen to know why my image isn't moving still would you?

Comment: var movement = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
this works!!I think you should specify "position"

Comment: sweet it totally does! Ok thank you very much, I've learned a lot here! I'd give you another upvote if I could haha

Answer (score 5):

SWIFT 3 UPDATES

```
 func moveImageView(imgView: UIImageView){
        var toPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -10.0)
        var fromPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
        var movement = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "movement")
        movement.isAdditive = true
        movement.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: fromPoint)
        movement.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: toPoint)
        movement.duration = 0.3
        imgView.layer.add(movement, forKey: "move")
    }
```